# Counting the sudden change in the points Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, graph, signals

I would like to count how many times the graph suddenly decreases and comes back to normal.
For example, here the graph suddenly decreases for 4 times.

[image]

Here, I only need to detect the detect sudden change(circled in red) and not the small changes(circled in black).

I actually tried with slope but it doesn't seem to work correctly

The above picture was only a small scale, the below picture shows the entire graph

[image]

It would be a great help for me if you answer my question. Thank you

Comment: Invert  you signal `x = -x` and then use `scipy.signal.find_peaks` with a threshold value for the parameter `distance`.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, since it was not a periodic signal, `distance` doesn't seem to fit correctly, but `prominence` did the job... You comment was very helpful..

Comment: The slope is simply too noisy. Maybe you can smooth the slope. Use a suitable filter, for example Savitzky-Golay filtering can compute smooth derivatives. Or simply some Gaussian weights within a moving data window.

Comment: hi @Trilarion , This output is after applying the filter, Without the filter, the slope is even more noisy.. But thank you for you comment, I got my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer to my own question.
Initially, I reversed the array.

```
array = numpy.max(array) - array
```

By, reversing the array all my valley points are converted to peaks. Thus, it became easy to find peaks using scipy.signals module.

```
find_peaks(array, prominence=(30 ,np.max(array)))
```

This returned all the peak points, the length of peak points is required for me..

Hope this question helped you.. Thank you..